# Why does my filereadline only read the last line?

Tags: c#

I want to create a form where I can generate payslip for employee. The payslip itself is based on level that I put on a text file
Here is my code

```
string line;
string a;
string b;
string[] row = new string[6];
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@string.filename);

bool pay = false;

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    row = line.Split(',');
    a = row[1];  /* This is my employee' name*/
    if (a == label8.Text)
    {
        b = row[5];
        pay = true;
    }
}

if (pay)
{
    b = row[5]; /* This is my employee's level*/
    int level = Convert.ToInt32(b);
    int basicsalary = level * 1000;
    label9.Text = basicsalary.ToString();
} 

file.Close();
```

I am using this kind of code a lot but somehow it's not working well in this form because it only read the last line.

Comment: Because you read the file in and put it in row, but then only after you finished reading all the file do you do things eg the "if (pay) ..

Comment: Only slightly related, but what does `@string.filename` mean? Which C# version introduced that?

Comment: @MechMK1 - its probably just a local variable called `string` since `string` is a reserved word he has to write `@string` and `.filename` is just a member of his local variable.

Comment: It reads every line - in that `while` loop, where any side effects from previous iterations through the loop are overwritten each time.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to stop reading from the file when you found that right line (by the `a == label8.Text` check?) in which case you're probably just missing a `break` inside that `if`.

Comment: @RandRandom Ah, that makes sense. I assumed that it was some new C# 8.0 feature or such

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code line by line? You can add watch variables and see what is happening. This might help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @MechMK1 string is another form where i put public static string filename = (path)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever omg man it's such a simple answer yet i did not manage to find it, thanks alot.